# Django CMS copy model instance issue

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv, django-cms, django-1.6

I have some issue with Django CMS 3.0 plugin model `copy_relations` function.
Example from [documentation](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html)

```
def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
    for associated_item in oldinstance.associated_item.all():
        # instance.pk = None; instance.pk.save() is the slightly odd but
        # standard Django way of copying a saved model instance
        associated_item.pk = None
        associated_item.plugin = self
        associated_item.save()
```

is not working and CMS is only modifying instance of plugin model. In this example I need to add `associated_item.id = None` for it to work.
This is not my first Django CMS project, but is first in 3.0. In previous versions I did follow documentation and everything was ok, but not this time.

The question is: is the documentation not up-to-date or I did something wrong on the way when creating models?

**edit:**
[Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/docs/topics/db/queries.txt) is where I found how to make Django CMS to save a copy of model instance:

```
Due to how inheritance works, you have to set both ``pk`` and ``id`` to None
```

I need to do this for all models with `copy_relations`, and I want to know why is this required.

Comment: `associated_item.pk = None` and `associated_item.id = None` are essentially one and the same thing. Are you sure you are not missing something else?

Comment: Maybe you have a field on your model explicitly named `pk`?

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev it's not `pk`. I need to do this for all one-to-many models.

Comment: if you found an answer yourself, it is worth to post it as an answer to the question and accept it as correct. It is perfectly OK if you're answering your own question and will help those who find this question later.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev I'm sorry for my poorly edit. I just want to know why I need to do it, and I only find `how` to fix it not `why`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously in your case `associated_item` points to a model which inherits from another model. There are two types of model inheritance in Django: [abstract and multi-table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

In the case of abstract inheritance, the base model is abstract, i.e. it is not in the database and just serves as a template for the models which inherit from it.

In the case of multi-table inheritance, all of the models are in DB, with submodels linked to the base model via a ForeignKey.

For regular models `.pk` and `.id` are one and the same thing (you can even check it with `my_model.pk is my_model.id`), while for multi-table submodels `.id` is the `id` field of the base model, and `.pk` is the ForeignKey used to connect the submodel to the base model. In fact, the numeric value of `.pk` and `.id` is still the same (because `.pk` points to `.id`), but nonetheless they are two separate columns in the DB. In my opinion this Django design decision is somewhat inconsistent, but that's what we have.

That's why you need to set both fields to `None` for Django to lose track of the model and see it as a new model instance.

Comment: I found a solution. I was inheriting from `CMSPlugin` class for associated item class, and documentation example inherits from `model.Models`. Thank you.